# def function python - Help me with syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I am a python newbie, learning the basics now. I tried the following def function.But it indicates an error. Can somebody tell me where I make the mistakes in the syntax.

(I wrote it with the proper indentation. but the Stakoverflow window does not indicate as I paste it)

```
# This will test the reverse function of the program

def rev(text) :
    text = input()
    return text [::-1]

print("Please Enter a word")
input()
rev(text)

input() # This is to avoid the screen closing immediately after executing the
        # program
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to assign a value to a variable before using it.

```
print("Please Enter a word")
input()
rev(text)
```

You are using `text` here, but you havn't assigned any value to it. You might want to do like this

```
print("Please Enter a word")
text = input()
rev(text)
```

Now, `input` will read data from the user and it will be available with `text`

**Suggestion 1:** As  @seaotternerd suggested in the comments, you don't need to `print` the message and read inputs, you can directly do,

```
input("Please Enter a word")
```

Comment: It also isn't necessary to print the prompt and then call input() separately. input("Please enter a word") will accomplish both.

Comment: @seaotternerd Thanks :) Added that in the answer :)